# OpenGL 3.3 GLX_ARB_create_context_profile is unavailable on Linux with bumblebee

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glew, glfw

I have problem with setting OpenGL 3.3 application with glfw. I get

```
OpenGL profile requested but GLX_ARB_create_context_profile is unavailable
```

error while I try to run my application through the optirun (I have Nvidia Optimus card, so there is no other way). Other OpenGL > 3.3 application works well with optirun (unigine heaven)... [Here is code I try to run](http://pastebin.com/h5Y7vHQN) and here is [result of "optirun glxinfo"](http://pastebin.com/1BXLE8P5).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you need this line?

```
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

Removing it should fix the problem.

If it segfaults check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302625/segmentation-fault-at-glgenvertexarrays-1-vao).

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. I have this code from opengl-tutorial.org. Removing this line makes the window close immediately after it have opened. EDIT: adding line from your link fixed this problem. Thank you.