# Cocoa OpenGLView with VAOs

Tags: cocoa, opengl

I'm hoping to make a custom NSOpenGL view on Cocoa. However, I'm having trouble using VAOs. In particular, when run, this dummy test view:

```
/// OpenGLTestView.h:
@interface OpenGLTestView : NSOpenGLView

- (void)prepareOpenGL;

@end

/// OpenGLTestView.m:
#import <OpenGL/gl3.h>

@implementation OpenGLTestView

- (void)prepareOpenGL {
    GLenum error;
    GLuint vertex_array;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array);
    error = glGetError();
    switch (error) {
        case GL_NO_ERROR:
            printf("GL_NO_ERROR\n");
            break;
        case GL_INVALID_ENUM:
            printf("GL_INVALID_ENUM\n");
            break;
        case GL_INVALID_VALUE:
            printf("GL_INVALID_VALUE\n");
            break;
        case GL_INVALID_OPERATION:
            printf("GL_INVALID_OPERATION\n");
            break;
        case GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION:
            printf("GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION\n");
            break;
        case GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
            printf("GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Unknown error\n");
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

prints this on output:

```
GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

Does Apple do something special with VAOs on cocoa? Or is there some initialization step that I'm missing?

Comment: Did you try `glGenVertexArraysAPPLE` (and the associated  `glBindVertexArraysAPPLE`)? Otherwise I would only expect it to work if you've installed GLEW or something.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302625/segmentation-fault-at-glgenvertexarrays-1-vao I just need to initialize GLEW. I thought I didn't need to because glGenVertexArrays is part of the regular OpenGL spec. I guess I'll research what exactly the relationship between GLEW and glGenVertexArrays is. If you post what you said again as an answer, I'll accept this as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was not creating an OpenGL 3.2 context (but calling 3.2 functions on it). Using the NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile attribute set to NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core to create a new context, then calling - (void)setOpenGLContext:(NSOpenGLContext *)context on the NSOpenGLView with the new context solves the problem.