# OpenGL not supported

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I run to a really odd problem while trying to generate vertex arrays with `openGL`. I am using windows 7 as platform, and I am using `GLEW 1.15` and `glm` as the `openGL` libraries with `SDL` as the interface.
The problem was that while trying to generate the vertex arrays using

```
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vertexArrayObject);
```

I came across with the following access violation error

> Unhandled exception at 0x7469CB49 in OpenGL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.

I am sure that I initialized `GLEW` correctly and set the glewExperimental as true before calling any `GLEW` functions

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
GLenum status = glewInit();
```

After running the *getInfo.exe* I found out that the `genVertexArrays` commmand was *MISSING* from *GLEW* I had installed to my PC. I then suspected I had a GPU or drivers problem which I chased down and found out that my PC was running with *Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family Graphics* card with a *CPU Intel Centrinto 2* - yes my PC is old.

I tried downloading drivers that support openGL version 4.5 or older but I couldn't find any that are supported from my CPU.

Does anyone know a way to go around this problem and make use of the `glgenVertexArrays` command with old or unsupported hardware? Maybe a command from older versions of openGL that produces the same result as `glGenVertexArrays` would be a really good help !

P.S I made sure to download the latest version of openGL. `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` returns Version 2.1.0 - Build 8.15.10.1840, which is not the one I've installed.

Comment: Are you using glew? If so, this might cause an issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302625/segmentation-fault-at-glgenvertexarrays-1-vao

Comment: I've tried to initialise glew but didn't work. I used the two lines of code just before the execution of the line.. ;/

Comment: Can you precise which libraries you are using, which platform you work on and show the code which initializes OpenGL and creates a GL context ?

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: I've also moved the initialization of GLEW before the creation of context

Comment: *Does anyone know a way to go around this problem and make use of the genVertexArrays command with old or unsupported hardware?* - the point of "unsupported" hardware is that it **is not supported**. Weird, innit? You could create your own sort-of polyfill for that, but it would be probably cheaper overall to just buy a newer development PC. In the long run, if you'll want advanced features, you'll need an advanced GPU.