# (Raylib) Cannot execute program in Notepad++. Exit code -1073741819

Tags: c, notepad++, execute, raylib

So I was running a C code in *Notepad++* but it exited with the code: -1073741819. I don't know what this means and I cannot find any explanation online. Please tell me how to fix this problem.

Here is the full console log:

```
> Setup required Environment
-------------------------------------
SET: RAYLIB_PATH=C:\raylib\raylib
$(RAYLIB_PATH) = C:\raylib\raylib
SET: COMPILER_PATH=C:\raylib\mingw\bin
$(COMPILER_PATH) = C:\raylib\mingw\bin
ENV_SET: PATH=C:\raylib\mingw\bin
$(SYS.PATH) = C:\raylib\mingw\bin
SET: CC=gcc
$(CC) = gcc
SET: CFLAGS=$(RAYLIB_PATH)\src\raylib.rc.data -s -static -Os -std=c99 -Wall -I$(RAYLIB_PATH)\src -Iexternal -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP
$(CFLAGS) = C:\raylib\raylib\src\raylib.rc.data -s -static -Os -std=c99 -Wall -IC:\raylib\raylib\src -Iexternal -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP
SET: LDFLAGS=-lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm
$(LDFLAGS) = -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm
CD: C:\raylib\raylib\examples\core
Current directory: C:\raylib\raylib\examples\core

> Clean latest build
------------------------
cmd /c IF EXIST core_basic_window.exe del /F core_basic_window.exe
Process started (PID=3288) >>>
<<< Process finished (PID=3288). (Exit code 0)

> Saving Current File
-------------------------
NPP_SAVE: C:\raylib\raylib\examples\core\core_basic_window.c

> Compile program
-----------------------
gcc -o core_basic_window.exe core_basic_window.c C:\raylib\raylib\src\raylib.rc.data -s -static -Os -std=c99 -Wall -IC:\raylib\raylib\src -Iexternal -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm
Process started (PID=1924) >>>
<<< Process finished (PID=1924). (Exit code 0)

> Reset Environment
--------------------------
ENV_UNSET: PATH
$(SYS.PATH) has been restored

> Execute program
-----------------------
cmd /c IF EXIST core_basic_window.exe core_basic_window.exe
Process started (PID=3748) >>>
<<< Process finished (PID=3748). (Exit code -1073741819)
================ READY ================
```

Here is the code since a lot of people asked (I watched a tutorial to set up the library and they run the exact same code but it didn't work.):

```
#include "raylib.h"

int main(void)
{
    // Initialization
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    const int screenWidth = 800;
    const int screenHeight = 450;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "raylib [core] example - basic window");

    SetTargetFPS(60);               // Set our game to run at 60 frames-per-second
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Main game loop
    while (!WindowShouldClose())    // Detect window close button or ESC key
    {
        // Update
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // TODO: Update your variables here
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Draw
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        BeginDrawing();

        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);

        DrawText("Congrats! You created your first window!", 190, 200, 20, LIGHTGRAY);

        EndDrawing();
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }

    // De-Initialization
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CloseWindow();        // Close window and OpenGL context
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    return 0;
}
```

This is what happens when I run it on Explorer and CMD window:

```
INFO: Initializing raylib 3.7
WARNING: GLFW: Error: 65543 Description: WGL: OpenGL profile requested but WGL_ARB_create_context_profile is unavailable
WARNING: GLFW: Failed to initialize Window
INFO: TIMER: Target time per frame: 16.667 milliseconds
```

Comment: All we can tell is that the program exits with that code. Without the program code it's impossible to tell what actually happens.

Comment: The value `-1073741819` is decimal for hex `C0000005` which is the code for access violation. You get that when your code accesses memory that does not belong to your process, typically by using null or otherwise uninitialized pointers (or possible attempting to use memory that you had once allocated but since passed to `free`).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some information about `core_basic_window.exe`. What is it supposed to do? What happens if you run it from Explorer or from a CMD window? Maybe there is an error in this program.

Comment: A program that you compile and run in a "random" editor crashes. You currently show everything except the program itself. That is much more important than what editor you use to write your code.

Comment: Using Notepad++ for C/C++ is not going to get you far. I strongly recommend switching to a proper IDE.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so how can I fix the problem?

Comment: @Bodo I think it is not needed because I followed a tutorial online and followed every step but it didn't work. I edited it and added the code to the question anyway.

Comment: Begin by learning how to use a *debugger* to catch crashes and locate where in your code it happens.

Comment: As far as I can see, the code does not contain anything suspicious, but access violation errors can also result from incompatibilities between libraries or bugs in libraries used by your program. You didn't answer the question "What happens if you run it from Explorer or from a CMD window?". Adding a link to the tutorial might also help us to ask more specific questions.

Comment: @Megarion Please don't use comments to provide requested information, [edit] your question instead. Sorry, I don't want to watch a 20 minutes video to find out if/where it contains information related to the installation of the library that might require additional questions. Find the file `core_basic_window.exe` and double-click it in the explorer or open a CMD window, `cd` to the location of the file `core_basic_window.exe` and type `core_basic_window`. If you don't know such basic tasks I suggest to start with more simple programming tasks that don't require additional libraries.

Comment: @Megarion I think the information is useful, although I don't know any details about raylib. Apparently it has something to do with `WGL_ARB_create_context_profile` or `OpenGL`. As I already wrote this could be an incompatibility between libraries. Maybe there is something missing or has a wrong version. Search for the error message and check if you find any clues. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/39704822/10622916

Comment: @Bodo I read that post. I found out that my OpenGL version is 3.1 but I didn't know what was requesting the core version that is incompatible with the OpenGL version. How can I check it?

Comment: @Megarion Check the source code and/or build scripts, Makefiles etc. If there is a specific place to ask questions about `raylib` you might get better answers there.

Comment: @Bodo So I managed to find the file that was requesting the Core version (2.0) and changed the request to Core version 3.1 but it gives me the same error when running in notepad++ and in Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by choosing your desired OpenGL version

You can achieve this by pressing F6, and on the right bottom corner there is a list, choose `raylib_source_compile`. And on line 4, choose the desired OpenGL version (GRAPHICS_API_OPENGL_33, GRAPHICS_API_OPENGL_21 and GRAPHICS_API_OPENGL_11) then press enter for it to recompile the Raylib library.

If it still doesnt work, go to `C:\raylib\raylib\src\config.h`, uncomment line 47 and recompile Raylib (which worked for me)