# WGL: OpenGL profile requested but WGL_ARB_create_context_profile is unavailable

Tags: c#, raylib

I'm using C# in Visual Studio 2017, I'm trying to work with Raylib 3.0.

This is my entire code:

```
using Raylib_cs;

namespace Raylib0 {
    static class Program
    {

    public static void Main()
        {
            Raylib.InitWindow(160, 90, "Test");

            while (!Raylib.WindowShouldClose())
            {
                Raylib.BeginDrawing();
                Raylib.ClearBackground(Color.WHITE);

                Raylib.DrawText("Hello, world!", 12, 12, 20, Color.BLACK);

                Raylib.EndDrawing();
            }

            Raylib.CloseWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

When i run it this return
'System.AccessViolationException' on line 21

On the window is written:

```
INFO: Initializing raylib 3.0
WARNING: GLFW: Error: 65543 Description: WGL: OpenGL profile requested but WGL_ARB_create_context_profile is unavailable
WARNING: GLFW: Failed to initialize Window
```

When i tried to use the newer Raylib versions in VS2019 the window had the same error.
I searched and apparently it's because my OpenGL version is very old, if I'm not mistaken my version is 3.1 and uses 3.3
Is there any way to change the OpenGL version that the program uses?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39704822/62576